# Disk Utility on MacOS 10.13.6

Tags: disk-utility

Folks;

Using Disk Utility on High Sierra (macOS 10.13.6) I've got the following:
[image: 2 unwanted partitions both formatted as 'Free Space']

The UI appears to allow each of them to be selected and the '-' button remains active. Note the text shown also specifically states that they can be deleted. However when 'Apply' is performed the following failure occurs:

[image: Operation Failed]

Short of reformatting the entire 1TB drive what can I do to rectify this?